# Finding a tuple with greatest value

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, max

Given these two lists:

```
first = [('-2.50', '1.91', '2.03'), ('3.00', '1.83', '2.08')]
second = [(('-2.50', 0.889258, 1.069258), ('3.00', 0.931381, 1.021381))]
```

It's a two-task challenge. Firslty, in list `second`, I need to identify a tuple with greatest value in it (while values at position `0` here: `-2.50` and `3.00` must be ignored). Then, as a second task, we need to output the corresponding tuple form list `first`. So it should result in:

```
('-2.50', '1.91', '2.03')
```

This is because the greatest value found in step first should be `1.069258` which is inside 1st tuple.

The snag I face here is finding the tuple with greatest value (I know I can use `max()` to find the value but I need the whole tuple), with the 2nd part of the problem I think I'll cope simply using the `if` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 1 line:

```
>>> max(zip(first,second[0]),key=lambda x:max(x[1][1:]))[0]
('-2.50', '1.91', '2.03')
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

```
>>> first [ max(enumerate(second[0]), key=lambda x: max(x[1][1:] ))[0] ]
('-2.50', '1.91', '2.03')
```

or:

```
>>> maxx = float("-inf")
>>> for i,x in enumerate(second[0]):
...     temp = max(x[1:]) 
...     if temp > maxx:
...         index = i
...         maxx = temp
...         
>>> first[i]
('-2.50', '1.91', '2.03')
```

Comment: Or, equivalently but more succinctly, `i = max(enumerate(second), key=lambda i_t: i_t[1][1:])[0]`.

Comment: Also note that your solution initially compares a float (`-inf`) to a tuple (`t[1:]`), which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a key function to compute the value by which each tuple is compared.  You want to compare the tuples by the largest value other than the first, so try

```
>>> max(second[0], key = lambda x: max(x[1:]))
('-2.50', 0.889258, 1.069258)
```